# Is it good practice to pass an already instanciated property into a using statement?

Tags: c#, properties, using, readonly

I came across this question when I was refactoring some of my code which was heavily depending on the Disposable pattern.

I do have a readonly field DbContext which is getting initialized in the constructor. Now I was wondering if I can just pass the field into a using block to get it disposed the right way. Or do I have to get rid of the field and the intialization to just initialize it within each using block

```cs
protected readonly DbContext _context;

public Repository(DbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id)
{
    using (_context)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(new CancellationToken(), id);
    }
}
```

I expect to apply the Dispose pattern the right way

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, however wrapping EF in a repository is a lot worse, and passing in and caching a db context and *disposing* it auto-magically is definitely a sin

Comment: In short you have bigger problems here

Comment: There is simple rule, if you create it then you must dispose and if you don't create it then don't dispose it.

Comment: @TheGeneral "wrapping EF in a repository is a lot worse" could you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: @MongZhu the statement should have read *"wrapping EF in a repository; passing in a dbcontext to cache; then auto-magically disposing it a is a lot worse (and a sin)"* meaning there is nothing wrong with the language feature as asked, however repositories over EF are a code smell to start with, and one that does magical unexpected things with disposable resources is clearly a code review fail and cause to rethink this entire problem

Comment: If you want to `return` result and only then call some method, then it's achieved by `try/finally`. For `Dispose()` call we have nice construct `using(...) { ... }`, doing exactly that. It's a bit unusual that you don't construct object yourself, that could indicate (as per other comments) or lead to a problem, e.g. if you get exception before you reach `using`, then nothing will be disposed and you may have memory leak. So the answer is: no, don't do it.

Comment: @TheGeneral thank you for your comment. Found [this nice article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/387135/should-entity-framework-6-not-be-used-with-repository-pattern) which (i guess) has a nice explanation/elaboration on your comment.

Comment: @MongZhu yeah basically says it way better than I could, nice find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two potential issues I see:

1. When you exit the `using` block, the object is disposed. If you then attempt to reuse it, you could get an `InvalidOperationException` thrown somewhere.
2. Some objects do not release all of their managed resources when disposed. They may still be referencing some large-ish objects, which can't be garbage collected while you have a reference to the disposable object. Case in point: `MemoryStream` - when you dispose it, the `MemoryStream` does not unreference its internal `byte[]` buffer. That means that until you unreference the stream itself, the array can't be collected and is effectively a memory leak.

So from my point of view, it's good to create a new object in the `using` statement, since it automatically both disposes it for you, *and* unreferences it so it can be collected.

A possible solution could be to instead inject a Factory object, and use its factory method to create the disposable object at the start of the `using` block.

Comment: And if you have to keep the reference for the life of the class instance, your class should implement `IDisposable`.